# Changing the value of "this"

Tags: javascript

I have this function :

```
Number.prototype.f=function()
{
    this=2;//This is not working
}
var x=0;
x.f();
alert(a);//Here I want that x equal 2
```

And I want that x is 2 at the end!

Comment: It would be good to explain _why_ you need to do this.  There may be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that precisely, but you can get a similar effect by explicitly using the Number constructor and overriding the `toString` method.

So, on the understanding that [this is sick and should never be seen in production code](http://jsfiddle.net/GFkFU/):

```
Number.prototype.f = function () {
    this.toString = function () {
        return "2";
    };
}
var x = new Number(0);
x.f();
alert(x);
```

​I've only tested it in Chrome.

Comment: You don't. The whole concept is crazy. You might have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but you would need to ask a question that explains your use case.

Comment: if for exemple i want to do a function like this : x.pow(y) and that the result go in x

Comment: I think just because it's more beautiful the first way

Comment: @Quentin I like how you solved OP's problem, but I hope you understand that I cannot, in good conscience, give you a vote up (even with your disclaimer). No hard feelings

Comment: and can i do it without writing var x=new Number(0); ?

Comment: @user1342369 — Opinions about what constitutes beautiful code do not trump writing idiomatic code.

Comment: @user1342369: This is one of the most _evil_ ideas I've seen in a long time.  **Do not do this!**

Comment: @user1342369 More beautiful? I don't think so. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, I guess. To me, it's just more confusing and harder to read and understand, because no function with numbers should do that: because Numbers are immutable. I agree with SLaks, please do not do this.

Comment: then i do it like that : x=x.pow(y) ?

Answer (score 2):

To some extent can do it. Numbers are passed by value, not be reference. So at best you can call `y = x.f();` with this function:

```
Number.prototype.f = function() { return 2; };
```

As for your comment:

> When we do array.push(2); the function push changes the array !

Of course it does. Arrays are objects and are passed by reference. The function might look something like this:

```
Array.prototype.push = function(val) {
    var t = this;
    t[t.length] = val;
};
```

Comment: Not if `x` is a primitive type (number and string are the main ones)

Comment: in case someone finds this useful, to copy an array without passing by reference -> `newarr = arr.slice(0)`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
<sup>(Pun intended)</sup>

Numbers are immutable.

Comment: Are you sure ? When we do array.push(2); the function push changes the array !

Comment: @user1342369: yes, because Arrays are data structures which are intended to change.  A number is always the same number, its identity doesn't change or depend on anything.

Comment: @user1342369: That's because _arrays_ are not immutable.